# How to get current displayed date range in full calendar jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have implemented [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) in my application. I am facing a problem for getting current displayed date range.
I want to get currently displayed date range in full calendar.
Please suggest me a proper solution.

For example please take a look on this image
[image]

In this I want to get "20 Sept" and "26 Sept".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this.

Add this function and call this. It will help you.

```
  function GetCalendarDateRange() {
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');
        var view = calendar.view;
        var start = view.start._d;
        var end = view.end._d;
        var dates = { start: start, end: end };
        return dates;
    }
```

Comment: you can simply return `view.start` and `view.end`

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('DD MMM');
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('DD MMM');
```

Comment: Working great! tks!

Answer (score 10):

```
In version 5.5.1 , you have to use

var view = calendarObj.view; // calendarObj is the reference to the fullcalendar
var start = view.activeStart;
var end = view.activeEnd;

start and end variables are Date.
```

Comment: To the point. It is still valid for version 6.

Answer (score 2):

In version 4.0, $().fullCalendar('next') no longer exists. You can use calender.next(), where calender is an instance of the object.

For example, to capture the start date:
    calender.view.activeStart.

See the documentation for more information: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation but user2682863 answer is the best in my opinion.

This way you use their API instead of using jquery to retrieve it from the frontend.

By accessing the View object (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object) you can get the current range like so (in Vue).

```
var calendarApi = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();
this.dates = calendarApi.state.dateProfile.currentRange;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using FullCalendar 5.8.0 with React. I found the following to work for me:

1. Create a ref and pass it into FullCalendar.

   const calendarRef = React.createRef()
   ...

   FullCalendar ref={calendarRef} ...
2. In my function where I need the know the visible date range:

   let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi()

   let dates = calendarApi.currentDataManager.state.dateProfile.activeRange

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already but none of the above methods worked for me in v5 so will post what did. After a rather frustrating search through the docs I came across this page. Using datesSet you can get start and end dates as well as the full view.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

If you add in a handler on init then this fires whenever the user changes the date via the buttons which is what I needed:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            dateClick: function (info) {
                alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr);
            },
            datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
                var start = dateInfo.start;
                var end = dateInfo.end;
                var startStr = dateInfo.startStr;
                var endStr = dateInfo.endStr;
                var timeZone = dateInfo.timeZone;
                var view = dateInfo.view;
            }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the current date range by accessing `calendar.state.dateProfile.currentRange`

where calendar is

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl}
```